# How rewrite webpack.config.js and add SASS for LARAVEL 8

Tags: laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-8, tailwind-css

How rewrite webpack.config.js and add SASS for LARAVEL 8

```
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
        .postCss("resources/css/app.css","public/css",[
            require("postcss-import"), 
            require("tailwindcss"), 
            require("autoprefixer")]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From `/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.mix.js`

> ```js
> // Full API
> // mix.js(src, output);
> // mix.react(src, output); <-- Identical to mix.js(), but registers React Babel compilation.
> // mix.preact(src, output); <-- Identical to mix.js(), but registers Preact compilation.
> // mix.coffee(src, output); <-- Identical to mix.js(), but registers CoffeeScript compilation.
> // mix.ts(src, output); <-- TypeScript support. Requires tsconfig.json to exist in the same folder as webpack.mix.js
> // mix.extract(vendorLibs);
> // mix.sass(src, output);
> // mix.less(src, output);
> // mix.stylus(src, output);
> // mix.postCss(src, output, [require('postcss-some-plugin')()]);
> // mix.browserSync('my-site.test');
> // mix.combine(files, destination);
> // mix.babel(files, destination); <-- Identical to mix.combine(), but also includes Babel compilation.
> // mix.copy(from, to);
> // mix.copyDirectory(fromDir, toDir);
> // mix.minify(file);
> // mix.sourceMaps(); // Enable sourcemaps
> // mix.version(); // Enable versioning.
> // mix.disableNotifications();
> // mix.setPublicPath('path/to/public');
> // mix.setResourceRoot('prefix/for/resource/locators');
> // mix.autoload({}); <-- Will be passed to Webpack's ProvidePlugin.
> // mix.webpackConfig({}); <-- Override webpack.config.js, without editing the file directly.
> // mix.babelConfig({}); <-- Merge extra Babel configuration (plugins, etc.) with Mix's default.
> // mix.then(function () {}) <-- Will be triggered each time Webpack finishes building.
> // mix.when(condition, function (mix) {}) <-- Call function if condition is true.
> // mix.override(function (webpackConfig) {}) <-- Will be triggered once the webpack config object has been fully generated by Mix.
> // mix.dump(); <-- Dump the generated webpack config object to the console.
> // mix.extend(name, handler) <-- Extend Mix's API with your own components.
> // mix.options({
> //   extractVueStyles: false, // Extract .vue component styling to file, rather than inline.
> //   globalVueStyles: file, // Variables file to be imported in every component.
> //   processCssUrls: true, // Process/optimize relative stylesheet url()'s. Set to false, if you don't want them touched.
> //   purifyCss: false, // Remove unused CSS selectors.
> //   terser: {}, // Terser-specific options. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#options
> //   postCss: [] // Post-CSS options: https://github.com/postcss/postcss/blob/master/docs/plugins.md
> // });
> ```

If you want to compile SASS, you'd just need to do the following:

```
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
   .sass("path/to/file.scss", "public/css");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add SASS and customize the output directory.

```
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .postCss("resources/css/app.css", "public/css",[
        require("postcss-import"),
        require("tailwindcss"),
        require("autoprefixer")]
    )
.sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css/sass");
```